# Lazy-load images using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to lazy load these images to improve the performance of the website. I'd like to have a default number of images already displayed and I want the remaining images to lazy load. This is what I have so far.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqEamR

```
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CmU3tnl.jpg"> 1 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TDdxS9H.png"> 2 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/39rpmwB.jpg"> 3 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/1lBZQ1B.png"> 4 </div>
 <div> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y5Ld4Qfh.jpg"> 5 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8HumESY.jpg"> 6 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CqCZBvk.png"> 7 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wQVPRVp.png"> 8 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9inrOjD.png"> 9 </div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jv0QZgx.jpg"> 10</div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xWmaeb6.png"> 11</div>
 <div> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/t73lyDn.png"> 12</div>

 <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

 body {
background-color: #f6f6f6;
width: 400px;
margin: 60px auto;
margin-top: 5px;
font: normal 13px/100% sans-serif;
color: #444;
 }
 img{
width:30px;
height:30px;
 }
 div {
display:none;
padding: 10px;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
 }
 .totop {
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
right: 20px;
 }
 .totop a {
display: none;
 }
 a, a:visited {
color: #33739E;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
margin: 10px 0;
 }
 a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
 }
 #loadMore {
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #33739E;
color: #fff;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
 }
 #loadMore:hover {
background-color: #fff;
color: #33739E;
 }

 (function() {
var divElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
var loadMore = document.querySelector('#loadMore');
var divNumber = 2;

loadMore.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < divNumber; i++) {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        if (i < divElements.length) {
            divElements[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

        if (i >= divElements.length) {
            loadMore.innerHTML = "Load Completed";
            return;
        }

    }
    divElements.splice(0, divNumber);

  });
 })();
 loadMore.click();
```

Comment: You should try searching google before coming to stackoverflow. I've found 10+ results at the top of the first page by searching the title of your question.

Comment: Lazy loading images isn't going to increase the performance of your site. You may get a faster initial load, but then you will get a slower interaction when the second group of image(s) are needed. Instead, you may want to consider loading the second group into `new Image()` elements and then display them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the imageurls in an javascript array. Then when you click on `load more`, it grabs the next imageurls from the array, you create an `img` element using javascript i.e. `var elem = document.createElement("img");` and set the `src` to your stored url from the array.